# Setting DataGrid.GroupStyle in style

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, grouping

I want to set DataGrid.GroupStyle in my style, so it will be mutual for all datagrids, and not in my view file, where I need to set it to each datagrid separatedly.
This is what I have now:

```
<Style  x:Key="DGView" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="DataGrid.CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DGCell}" />
</Style>

<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DGSecondaryView}" >

    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GIView}" >
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BookID" Binding="{Binding BookID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource StringToOffset}}" Width="3*" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sequence" Binding="{Binding Sequence}" Width="3*" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource  Numeric}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

What I want, is to insert the following code into the style tag. Is it possible?

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GIView}" >
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this for a ListBox so I created new control that inherited from ListBox and added a bindable and stylable property. The same could be done for a DataGrid.

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox 
{ 
    public GroupStyle DefaultGroupStyle 
    { 
        get { return (GroupStyle)GetValue(DefaultGroupStyleProperty); } 
        set { SetValue(DefaultGroupStyleProperty, value); } 
    } 

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DefaultGroupStyle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc... 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultGroupStyleProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultGroupStyle", typeof(GroupStyle), typeof(MyListBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, DefaultGroupStyleChanged)); 

    private static void DefaultGroupStyleChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        ((MyListBox)o).SetDefaultGroupStyle(e.NewValue as GroupStyle); 
    } 

    private void SetDefaultGroupStyle(GroupStyle defaultStyle) 
    { 
        if (defaultStyle == null) 
        { 
            return; 
        } 

        if (this.GroupStyle.Count == 0) 
        { 
            this.GroupStyle.Add(defaultStyle); 
        } 
    } 
}
```